# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting error in chrome browser,when running the web application,but in IE the application is running fine.
Please suggest.

```
var cb_addEventListener = function(obj, evt, fnc) {
    // W3C model
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fnc, false);
        return true;
    } 
    // Microsoft model
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        return obj.attachEvent('on' + evt, fnc);
    }
    // Browser don't support W3C or MSFT model, go on with traditional
    else {
        evt = 'on'+evt;
        if(typeof obj[evt] === 'function'){
            // Object already has a function on traditional
            // Let's wrap it with our own function inside another function
            fnc = (function(f1,f2){
                return function(){
                    f1.apply(this,arguments);
                    f2.apply(this,arguments);
                }
            })(obj[evt], fnc);
        }
        obj[evt] = fnc;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

var myForm = document.getElementById("prsregistrationform");
cb_addEventListener( myForm, 'submit', function() {
    return validateForm(document.partnerSimulationForm, document.prsregistrationform);
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: var myForm = document.getElementById("prsregistrationform");
    
    cb_addEventListener( myForm, 'submit', function() { return validateForm(document.partnerSimulationForm, document.prsregistrationform); } );   I am using jsp

Comment: You have to make sure that `myForm` is defined, ie, there is an element with the id `prsregistrationform`.

Comment: Your problem is in lie `if (obj.addEventListener) {`. You assume that `obj` will be a non-`null` object, which seems not to be the case. Check if there is an element with `id="prsregistrationform"`.